# Python and xlwings: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, path, xlwings

I am having issues writting some data in Excel from xlwings. The script work perfectly in other folders, but once I add the script into a folder which is contained in OneDrive it doesn't work (it does work for other colleagues in their own computers, same folder structure).

Code looks like this:

```
    import xlwings as xw

    # Path to Excel Database
    excel_file_path = 'Process control file_DST_Östersund.xlsx'

    # Load the Excel workbook
    sheet_name = 'Log'
    print('test2')
    workbook = xw.Book(excel_file_path)
    last_row = workbook.sheets[sheet_name].cells.end('down').row
    workbook.sheets[sheet_name].range('A' + str(last_row + 1)).value = data

    # Specify the sheet name
    sheet_name = 'MSL'
    print('test3')
    # Load the Excel workbook
    workbook = xw.Book(excel_file_path).sheets(sheet_name)
    print('test4')
```

And the result look like this

```
test2
test3
An error occurred: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\EHS and Site Management Östersund\\ARCHIVE\\ARCHIVE Egenkontroll och tillstånd Östersund\\ARKIV Tillstånd och egenkontroll Frösön\\Frösöstrand Tillstånd och Kemikalier\\listor inköp offerter frösön\\datorer skrivare mm'
```

Two weird things:

1. xlwings is able to open and write the first part of the code, I get the right data into the sheet called 'Log', but once it goes to the sheet called 'MSL' it crashes.
2. The error that I get is not even the right path for the file that I am trying to open. My script is in the same folder as the Excel file I am trying to open, but in case it is needed, the right path is `C:\Users\Oil Samples`

Any help with this issue?
Thanks!!

I have tried having absolute and relatives paths with no success, I always get the same error with the same file error path.

Comment: Are you sure the code you've shown is producing that error. There's nothing in the error message that alludes to your file. What happens if you try to open the file directly? e.g., *open(excel_file_path, "rb")*

Comment: Yes, I have no idea how it is getting to that other path. I think I might have found a problem, I am calling twice the xw.Book(), I deleted the second one and now only change in between sheets, and it might have worked.

Comment: You might also want to try the superior *openpyxl* module

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually tried with that one earlier on in the project, the issue with it was that I couldn't find a good way to edit Excel when the file is in a cloud service. Multiple people might be in the same file at the same time editing, xlwings is more flexible in that way since it pastes data on each cell rather than building a whole new document and overwritting it. As I said, I couldn't find a better way with openpyxl, there probably is one :)

Comment: @CtrlZ just because a library fits your use case better doesn't make it superior, right? xlwings and OpenPyXL serve different purposes.